# SVM predict on OpenCV: how can I extract the same number of features

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm

I am play with OpenCV and SVM to make a classifier to predict facial expression. I have no problem to classify test dadaset, but when I try to predict a new image, I get this:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F) in cv::ml::SVMImpl::predict

Error is pretty clear and I have a different number of columns, but of the same type.
I do not know how to achieve that, because I have a matrix of dimensions 1xnumber_of_features, but numbers_of_features is not the same of the trained and tested samples. How can I extract the same number of features from another image? Am I missing something?

To train classifier I did:

- Detect face and save ROI;
- Sift to extract features;
- kmeans to cluster them;
- bag of words to get the same numbers of features for each image;
- pca to reduce;
- train on train dadaset;
- predict on test dadaset;

On the new image I did the same thing.

I tried to resize the new image to the same size, but nothing, same error ( and different number of columns, aka features). Vectors are of the same type (CF_32F).

**[EDIT 1]** Let's try to be more specific.
After  succesfuly trained my classifier, I save SVM model in this way

```
svmClassifier->save(baseDatabasePath);
```

Then I load it when I need to do real time prediction in this way

```
cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> svmClassifier;
svmClassifier = cv::ml::StatModel::load<ml::SVM>(path);
```

Then loop,

```
while (true) 
{
    getOneImage();
    cv::Mat feature = extractFeaturesFromSingleImage();
    float labelPredicted = svmClassifier->predict(feature);
    cout << "Label predicted is: " << labelPredicted << endl;
}
```

But `predict` returns the error. feature dimension is 1x66, for example. As you can see below, I need like 140 features

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<opencv_ml_svm>
  <format>3</format>
  <svmType>C_SVC</svmType>
  <kernel>
    <type>RBF</type>
    <gamma>5.0625000000000009e-01</gamma></kernel>
  <C>1.2500000000000000e+01</C>
  <term_criteria><epsilon>1.1920928955078125e-07</epsilon>
    <iterations>1000</iterations></term_criteria>
  <var_count>140</var_count>
  <class_count>7</class_count>
  <class_labels type_id="opencv-matrix">
    <rows>7</rows>
    <cols>1</cols>
    <dt>i</dt>
    <data>
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6</data></class_labels>
  <sv_total>172</sv_total>
```

I do not know how achieve 140 features, when SIFT, FAST or SURF just give me around 60 features. What am I missing?

**EDIT 2**: I am going to try to be more formal: how can I put my real time sample on the same dimension of train and test dataset?

**EDIT 3:**
Extract features with sift and push on a vector of mat.

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> featuresVector;
for (int i = 0; i < numberImages; ++i)
{
    cv::Mat face = cv::imread(facePath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::Mat featuresExtracted = runExtractFeature(face, featuresExtractionAlgorithm);
    featuresVector.push_back(featuresExtracted);
}
```

Get total features extracted from all images.

```
int numberFeatures = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < featuresVector.size(); ++i)
{
    numberFeatures += featuresVector[i].rows;
}
```

Prepare a mat to cluster features (I tried to follow [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/de/d63/kmeans_8cpp-example.html) example)

```
cv::Mat featuresData = cv::Mat::zeros(numberFeatures, featuresVector[0].cols, CV_32FC1);
int currentIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < featuresVector.size(); ++i)
{
    featuresVector[i].copyTo(featuresData.rowRange(currentIndex, currentIndex + featuresVector[i].rows));
    currentIndex += featuresVector[i].rows;
}
```

Perform clustering (I do not know how this parameter suite my case, my I think can be ok for now)

```
cv::Mat labels;
cv::Mat centers;
int binSize = 1000;
kmeans(featuresData, binSize, labels, cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::COUNT + cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 100, 1.0), 3, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

Prepare a mat to perform bow.

```
cv::Mat featuresDataHist = cv::Mat::zeros(numberImages, binSize, CV_32FC1);
for (int i = 0; i < numberImages; ++i)
{
    cv::Mat feature = cv::Mat::zeros(1, binSize, CV_32FC1);
    int numberImageFeatures = featuresVector[i].rows;
    for (int j = 0; j < numberImageFeatures; ++j)
    {
        int bin = labels.at<int>(currentIndex + j);
        feature.at<float>(0, bin) += 1;
    }
    cv::normalize(feature, feature);
    feature.copyTo(featuresDataHist.row(i));
    currentIndex += featuresVector[i].rows;
}
```

PCA to try to reduce dimension.

```
cv::PCA pca(featuresDataHist, cv::Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, 50/*0.90*/);
cv::Mat feature;
for (int i = 0; i < numberImages; ++i) 
{
    feature = pca.project(featuresDataHist.row(i));
}
```

Comment: If you don't have the same number of features in the trained and tested samples, how (rather why?) do you expect SVM to work?

Comment: @RickM. Samples from trained and tested dataset have the same number of features, but now new image.

Comment: **Why** do you need 140 features?

Comment: @rayryeng As you can see, my model have 140 features and I need to get the same number of features (opencv tells me that with Assertation failed) to try to classify a new image. Am I missing something?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. WHY do you need 140 features for training? Can't you use 66?

Comment: @rayryeng sure, I can, but if do not know how many features an image in real time can have, how can I chose a right number of features?

Comment: Sure you can.  That's defined by the number of features in SIFT (usually 128) and your BOF histogram, usually defined as the total number of centroids defined after vector quantization. I don't see why the total number of features for your test images changes when you apply the same transformation. We can't begin to understand where this discrepancy occurs until you show us more of your code - specifically when you calculate the SIFT features and calculate the BOF histograms.

Comment: @rayryeng I am going to add it.